# What are some practical PHP namespacing solutions?

Tags: php, class, namespaces

This is the scenario (it's a bit specific, but still general enough to apply to any php lib):

WordPress 3.2.1 or earlier versions (PHP code base, PHP5 w/ and w/o name spacing available) ... I have created a small PHP library with a few class names (WPAlchemy_MetaBox, WPAlchemy_MediaAccess) ... developers have started to use the classes in plugins/themes of which WordPress can have many installed (in the same environment), so the possibility of two or more plugins using the library is likely (collision can occurs with the class names obviously)

I am currently thinking that each release could have a unique class name (with the version number or something) ... I could abstract this a bit with a simple loader of some sort (for simplicity).

**I would like to get some best practices to solve the above.**

- prevent name collisions
- allow developers to use a specific version if desired

If there are other SO posts that solve this please let me know, additionally please feel free to reword the question with additional bullet point objectives.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent collisions, use an autoloader (see [`spl_autoload_register`](http://php.net/spl_autoload_register)). So if you share the library and each sharer uses an autoloader, the class name collision (redeclare class fatal error) won't happen any longer.

This does not solve the version problem (e.g. to have different classes from the same family but with different versions).

One simple solution (combined with the autloader) is to offer the library as a plugin. Each time the library get's update, update the plugin. The plugin offers just the autoloader and the classes.

Other plugins that want to make use of the library, must make your library-plugin a dependency, e.g. checking for it and telling the user to install it if it's not available or just automatically install it.

If you offer a sample plugin that does this for a demo (SDK), I think many of the libraries users will adopt.